# How to take position of controls on View in android

Tags: android, controls, position

Now i have a problem need help from everyone:

I want to take positions (X, Y or Top-Left) of Button on LinearLayout but i can't although i have try many functions as :getBottom(); getTotalPaddingLeft(); getLocationOnScreen(local); getLocationOnWindow(local) but not success!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override method onLayout of view this method:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onLayout%28boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29

```
protected void onLayout (boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

So use this method to get position of view: